# Find all the possible numbers whose sum is x but ....

Tags: permutations, combinations

I want to find all the number whose sum is x but

but series of number start with a specific number and next number is always smaller then the number before it

For example I want 41 but first number in the series is
11
I want all the combination of number which start from 11 and succeeding number are smaller than previous number like
11 + 9 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 41

Numbers are 11 and less than 11 and each number occurs only one time, and sum of them is 41.
11+10+9+8+3 = 41

I want a method so I can effectively generate all such combinations.

Comment: It is still unclear from your example for what precisely you are looking.

Comment: I want all the number whose sum is 41 but the combination of numbers start with 11 and following numbers are smaller than the number before it like 11 and next number is 10 and next is 9 while making sure when you add all these numbers the sum is 41, does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if we remove the condition that the numbers are in a decreasing order, than we left with searching for all the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of an integer - we can sort the values at the end.
The referenced Wikipedia article discusses variations of this problem, like if you want strictly smaller values than you want **distinct parts**, and if you have an initial value, than you want **restricted part size**. At the bottom there is a link that says how to generate these values, I did not check it out and I also never actually generated such values, but it should serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Since $\sum_{k=1}^{11} k = 66$, your question **bijects** to the (*easier to manually count*) question of :

How many distinct subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots,11\}$ are there such that the sum of all of the numbers in the subset exactly equals $(66-41) = 25?$

Given the simplicity of the alternative question, and given that no elegance presents itself to me, I would attack the alternative question manually.

Naturally, if anyone has a more elegant approach, I would consider that approach superior, regardless of the simplicity of the question being attacked.

**Note**
I reject the [Stars and Bars approach](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) because the number of (*analogous*) variables is **not** fixed.

**Also**, the actual query is **not** the number of solutions, but rather to obtain an enumeration of each possible solution.

Comment: So you saying there are 25 possible combinations whose sum equals 41? and you didn't tell me how I obtain each one of them.

Comment: @Zetock No, you misread my answer.  What I was saying was that (for example) with $11 + 9 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 41$, you also have $7 + 8 + 10 = 25.$  The idea is that the set $\{7,8,10\}$ represents all of the numbers from $\{1,2,3,\cdots,11\}$ that are **missing** from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,9,11\}$.  Please re-read my answer in that light.  I focused on finding subsets of numbers that **sum to** $(25)$ simply because, since $(25) < (41)$, it is easier.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Zetock As for identifying and enumerating each subset of $\{1,2,3,\cdots,11\}$ that leads to the sum of $(25)$, I see nothing better than doing this manually, **without any attempt at elegance**.

Comment: thanks I get it now, but need a better method i can't do it manually as I want to do it with larger numbers. thanks for the answer.